# Stuck on Flutter Apple Login credential process

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, apple-sign-in, apple-login

I am trying to implement apple login through my flutter firebase app. I've done all the processes for apple sign in such as apple app id registration, service id registration, ios set up, and firebase hosting.

So I used sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0 for my app. However, if I run the code on my ios simulator (iPhone 11 (ios 15.5)). it just stuck on log in
status and got no change as the picture I uploaded

If I run the code below, the flutter system only prints '1' and no error message or any result come out.

I will leave the flutter doctor -v screenshot as well[image]

```
print(1);
final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
  scopes: [
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
  ],
);
print(2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved
I solved this problem by using ios 13 simulator device